# How can I use Activemq Virtual topic?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, spring-jms

I have topic **VirtualTopic.Orders** and 2 queue **Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Orders**, **Consumer.B.VirtualTopic.Orders**. I send message to **VirtualTopic.Orders**, that had received, but **Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Orders** and **Consumer.B.VirtualTopic.Orders** did not received.

This my guide http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html.

Comment: Provide more explanation, like is there any error you are facing or some code part you tried will help anyone to answer.

Comment: Was there any solution for this? Where did you configure the Virtual topic? Did you also have to configure the Consumer topics/queues in the activemq xml? If yes did you configure it as a queue or topic?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you have not added the configuration to the activemq.xml to enable the feature that aligns with your destination naming convention:

```
<destinationInterceptors>
 <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    <virtualDestinations>
      <virtualTopic name="VirtualTopic.>" prefix="Consumer.*."   selectorAware="false"/>
    </virtualDestinations>
  </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
</destinationInterceptors>
```

Comment: I had added the configuration to the activemq.xml, but it's not work

Comment: Post your configuration